# Symfony 5 : translate Arabic numbers to Modern numbers

Tags: translation, symfony4

I use Symfony 5, and I checked Arabic like the default language of the website.

but when I write a number on the database and get it, the Symfony translate it automatically to Arabic numbers `( from [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] to [١,٢,٣,٤,٥,٦,٧,٨,٩] )`.

is there any solution to use modern numbers in place of Arabic numbers ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the language of your browser (and thus the requests) ? Sounds more like an issue where your browser is "being smart" and translating to Arabic for you. (Example when checking with CLI, what is out of: `curl https://your.domain` ?)

Comment: When I set my English like default language on Symfony, I get the modern numbers, but when I switched to Arabic I get to Arabic numbers, and I want to use modern in place of Arabic numbers (PS: My browser language is English)

Comment: Uhm, does it not seem logical to you that you get served in the language you have requested in the Request? If you want to override a language you could use an EventSubscriber to override the Request's parameter `_locale` if you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searches and analyzing I found that issue come from the NumberType input, so I changed to the TextType input